# Trouble with fixing search container margins on mobile

Tags: html, css, search, mobile

(some background, I'm a designer who's trying to learn how to code!)

I'm having trouble fixing the search input field surrounding area for mobile for https://www.agjeans.com. It's cut off at the top in mobile view. While in Chrome dev tools, I'm able to seemingly fix the issue, the reality is that when I input these code changes they seem to do nothing.

I've done a variety of code changes, such as

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.header-search .mobile-search-active+.search-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 72px;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

and have done

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.search-wrapper {
   margin-top: 30px !important;
   }
}
```

and also

```
.search-button-container.mobile-search-active {
    margin-top:  30px;
}
```

As you can see, these resulting changes look great in dev tools, but do nothing when actually implementing the code. I've looked at the site on my own personal phone as well as in the browser, so the issue remains persistent.

Also, if I add something ridiculous (like specifying 300px margin-top for the header) it does show in the site, so I know it's just with this issue. What's the correct solution?

[image: Dev tools]

[image: Image of issue]

Comment: Hello. Do you mean this problem? - https://ibb.co/dg8R0SM

Comment: Yes! Exactly. @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: add `top: 15px` in `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) .header-search .search-button.active` and `top: -37px` in `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) .header-search .mobile-search-active + .search-wrapper`

Comment: So I added the code you proposed and it still doesn't seem to work at all for some reason: https://ibb.co/N97dxw6

Comment: ok i will look again, but later

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

All this is done in the `style.min.css` file. This animation is the result of all the steps below - https://ibb.co/zJWnLbf.

Initially your selector `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) .header-search .mobile-search-active + .search-wrapper` looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .header-search .mobile-search-active + .search-wrapper {
     padding-bottom: 72px;
     border: 0;
 }
}
```

You need to add a `top: -37px`. And now this selector should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .header-search .mobile-search-active + .search-wrapper {
     padding-bottom: 72px;
     border: 0;
     top: -37px;
 }
}
```

Ok, now we need to correct the `closing cross`. To do this, you need to turn to the selector `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) .header-search .search-button.active` looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {
 .header-search .search-button.active {
    background: url(../images/close-x-button.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 10px;
    top: -32px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
 }
}
```

You need to add a `top: 10px` and remoeve a `top: -32px`. And now this selector should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {
 .header-search .search-button.active {
    background: url(../images/close-x-button.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
 }
}
```

And the same `top: 10px` rule needs to be added for the `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 370px) .header-search .search-button.active` selector. As a result, it should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 370px) {
 .header-search .search-button.active {
    background: url(../images/close-x-button.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergey! Thanks for your detailed response. Unfortunately, I'm unable to edit the original selectors (can't directly access that), so I have to have separate selectors with the !important syntax (e.g. top: 10px !important) in the code. You can search for these additions in the footer of the site.

Comment: Hi Tiffany. Please tell me where are you inserting your selectors? In a separate css file, or in the html structure, with `<style>...</style>` tags?

Comment: Hi Sergey. I'm inserting the selectors in a separate file, where I can include html and css (in <style></style>) tags. This file overrides the original code, with the caveat that in order to have these changes work I need to add !important in the selector.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If not, then it will show the contents of your css file.